# Is Extant only the SECOND national primetime scripted TV-drama with a female African-American lead?

Tags: first-appearance, casting

Is Extant only the SECOND national primetime scripted TV show with an African-American female lead? I'm looking specifically for mainstream networks. To be explicit, BET is not that - talkshow and reality TV isn't it either.

Only other show I can think of is Scandal.

I've noticed that a majority of TV shows have this casting mold:

1. Older white male
2. Younger white male / Younger white female
3. Younger white female/ Younger white male
4. Minority (used to be African-American, now interchangeable with Asians/Latinos)

I have also noticed the following:

- Mainstream, primetime shows with a female lead are still a minority.
- To be sure there ARE some shows that have "a" Afram female protagonist, but they're pretty much token.
- Ever noticed how African-Americans play authority figures that are completely minor roles? Like judges, doctors? E.g. Tamara Tunny on CSI Miami
- "The Rush Hour" movies were completely shocking, because there was NO white lead at all.
- There are a FEW shows with MALE Afram leads, but these hardly ever lasted more than one season, only the Unit comes to mind, and whether Haysbert was the main protagonist is debatable

Comment: What about "Rogue" with Thandie Newton? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_%28TV_series%29

Comment: Dang, you're right. We could nitpick and say that she's half-white, but then again, Halle, and under Jim Crow, she'd be lynched like the rest of us ... ;)
Thanks, i'm downloading it now.
Unlike Cult, it's a real lead, and she IS an exceptional actress, better than Halle, but not better than Viola Davis.

Comment: Why not make Rogue an answer?

Comment: How would you figure in ensemble shows where, for the most part, everyone is the same and individuals gain or lose screen time depending on how the story lines progress? (i.e. Southland, which didn't have a 'lead' per se, but did have two African American detectives partnered, with the female easily considered a primary in multiple storylines)

Comment: How about __[Nichelle Nichols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichelle_Nichols#Star_Trek)__ from __[Star Trek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060028/)__ (1966): _"She gained popular recognition by being one of the first black women featured in a major television series not portraying a servant."_ - Or a more recent example: [Nicole Beharie](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2718512/), the female lead of __[Sleepy Hollow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2647544/)__.

Comment: Nichols, while daring to the white dominance, was pretty token. Did she, other than that kiss, ever get a significant story line, did she ever get a story line that DIDN'T involve men, or romance or seduction or damsel-in-distress?

It is sad, but her role wasn't a real role. Just imagine this: a mainstream show with mostly black females who all had character development and a young white shirtless dude who only served as a tool for sexually  tinted lines?

Comment: Just imagine this: a mainstream show with mostly black females who all had character development + a young white shirtless dude who only served as a tool for sexually  tinted lines. Has there ever been a show like that? Will there ever be one? No.
I'm on the fence about Sleepy Hollow cos Beharie doesn't have 1st billing, which is a big deal. "How to get away with murder is refered to as "that Viola Davis show", which is really different.

Answer (score 3):

As early as 1974 on the ABC network, there was a show called [Get Christy Love!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Christie_Love!), with Teresa Graves as the lead. The Wikipedia article sources Jet, a magazine devoted to African American performers and artists, and her profile in the Nov 1974 issue names no preceding black television lead actress, which it probably would have.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I missed the 2013 show [Deception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245029/epdate), with Meagan Goode, which makes Extant the fourth show of this kind.